# How to properly create and scaffold multiple entry points for an Angular project

Tags: angular

I have an app that has 3 entry points.

#### Client app

Single route app.

#### Corporate app

This is basically a list of multiple links to different customer app. I'd love this app to just seamlessly transition, but I will probably use basic navigation; exit the corporate app enter the customer.

#### Internal app

This will use 90% of all component created for this project. This app will even contain previews of UI of the other apps, thus the high percentage.

Users of the internal app will use the corporate app as well as a client app, corporate app users will also use the client app. Only client app users won't use other apps.

---

I know I can create projects using `ng generate application <name>`.

### The question:

What are the best practices when one wants to share components between multiple projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create libraries to contain your common items. I'd suggest looking a the Nx structure; it has schematics where you create your three apps, a library, and it builds out the configuration and directory structure. You can then develop using ng serve appname and it works as you would expect. [nx.dev](https://nx.dev)

Comment: Quite hard to wrap the head around it, but will work